# Save files in assets from ftp in android

Tags: android

I was wondering if is possible to save files from ftp to assets in android. This is method to download files from ftp, but how can I save this files in assets?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't. Assets folder is r/o(read-only) at runtime. You can use a other [Storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) instead